# PHP: Changing UTC time to Pacific (PST/PDT)

Tags: php

I have a Datetime object and get the time with the following:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $temp['date']->getTimeStamp());
```

I would like to be able to convert this into California's current time, but I need to account for PST and PDT for the time offset. It could be -7 or -8 hours depending on the time of the year. How can I dynamically obtain `$today` for the correct Pacific time?

Comment: I came here hoping to know the right time zone name in php for PST/PDT and I don't have my answer and the duplicate doesn't give it because it is for CENTRAL TIME ZONE. So I disagree with this duplicate

Comment: I agree with Baptiste. I came looking for the same thing and that duplicate is not the correct answer. I get tired of all these holier than thou moderators dissing posts on this board.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use strtotime to change the timezone, like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT'); //Make sure the time is GMT
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $today."\n";

$today_utc = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $today." GMT+3"));

echo $today_utc."\n";

$today_9 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $today." GMT-9"));

echo $today_9;
```

demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f08c0c69b415464bbee68fd1cdaaf1e7f4f1872b

So in your case your code could be:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $temp['date']->getTimeStamp());
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $today." GMT-9"));
```

Comment: does this account for Daylight Savings?