# PHP Convert a Timezone Time Apr 6, 2016 6:39:18 PM to Pacific Timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, datetimeoffset

Right now it is 1:53 PM in California.

I want to convert this time `Apr 6, 2016 8:53:18 PM` which is 7 hours ahead of California time. I want to convert it to California time no matter if PST or PDT is in effect.

Not sure what function to use.

I tried

```
$timestamp = "2016-04-06 13:53:56";


$date = new DateTime($timestamp);

echo $date->format('M j, Y g:i:s A') . "<br>";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));   
echo $date->format('M j, Y g:i:s A') . "<br>";  // Pacific time

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('M j, Y g:i:s A') . "<br>";  // Berlin time
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368632/php-changing-utc-time-to-pacific-pst-pdt

Comment: Ok thanks I guess I didn't use very good keywords to search.